# Is there any way to put the images on the left of the screen centered with the text on React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hey guys I have a question about React Native.  I want the top cube image to be next to the text that says "OLL 1" and the bottom cube to be next to the text that says "OLL 2".  My views look like this:

```js
<View style={styles.images}>
  <Image source={require('./rubiks-cube.png')} style={styles.image}></Image>
  <Image source={require('./OLL.jpg')} style={styles.image}></Image>
</View>
<View style={styles.algorithms}>
  <Text style={styles.algorithmstext}>OLL 1</Text>
  <Text style={styles.algorithmstext}>OLL 2</Text>
</View>
```

and my style sheet looks like this:

```js
algorithms: {
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: 'column',
},
algorithmstext: {
  fontSize: 40,
  padding: 20,
},
images: {
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: 'column',
  alignItems: 'flex-end',
  position: 'absolute',
},
image: {
  height: 100,
  width: 100,
},
```

but the app looks like this.  Is there any way to put the images on the left of the screen?  I need to keep the position absolute so that the images don't push the text down, but if I put the position: 'absolute', on the "image" style then the images stay on top of each other and you can only see one of the images.  Does anyone know how I could fix this?

[image: App Screenshot]

Comment: what is exactly that you want? can you share the screenshot of it?

Answer (score 0):

Try below style

```
images: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
//    position: 'absolute', <-- Remove this
  },
```